# AngularJS : ng model not updating via date picker

Tags: angularjs

I have a datetimepicker.

Overall, it works fine and updates the text box fine. However, when I place a ng-model onto the input field, nothing gets passed through to the binding at the bottom of the page.

Here!s the form I'm using :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker3'>
        <input type='text' ng-model="package.timeA" value="" class="form-control" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my JS code :

```
$(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
        format: 'LT'
    });
});
```

Comment: Please attach comments if down-voting a question.

Answer (score 0):

For the input box give some id or class name then initialize datepicker with that id or class

```
 <input type='text' ng-model="package.timeA" value="" class="mydatePicker form-control" />


 $('.mydatePicker ').datetimepicker();
```

It will work.

Comment: Didn't work, I'm trying to get the ng model to work, the date time picker works fine.

Comment: please create fiddle link

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use $apply who allow to force reload of the variable and $setViewValue who allow to set the variable of the view.

add ng-change on your input tag and pass the date.

In your controller you can make a function like this:

```
$scope.onChange = function(package.timeA)
{
    $scope.$apply(function (){
         YourCtrl.$setViewValue(package.timeA)
    }
}
```